# Unbound Prefix Error when XML Parsing in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, toolbar

I want to add Toolbar widget to my application. So when I add xml code to layout file I got Unbound prefix error. What should I do to solve this?

My layout.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dizikolikk.MainActivity" >


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs when you use an undefined namespace in your XML layout (in this case it's the 'app' namespace)

**You need to add**

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to your XML layout.